# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase only when uploading an image to firebase storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm getting this error only for firebasestorage and not for firestore

[What the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeZC9.png)

**Pubspec.yaml file:**

```
name: find_missing_people
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.1.0 <4.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^4.12.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^4.12.0
  firebase_core: ^2.22.0
  firebase_dart: ^1.1.1
  firebase_database: ^10.3.4
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  geocoding: ^2.1.1
  geolocator: ^10.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.5
  image: ^4.1.3
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  lottie: ^2.7.0
  permission_handler: ^11.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/logo.svg
    - assets/google_logo.png
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Lobster
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Lobster-Regular.ttf
    #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
    #         style: italic
    - family: Tanker
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Tanker-Regular.ttf

    - family: montserrat
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts\monsterrat\Montserrat-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-ThinItalic.ttf
        #   style: italic
        #   weight: 100
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-ExtraLight.ttf
        #   weight: 200
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-ExtraLightItalic.ttf
        #   style: italic
        #   weight: 200
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf
        #   weight: 300
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-LightItalic.ttf
        #   style: italic
        #   weight: 300
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
        #   weight: 400
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Medium.ttf
        #   weight: 500
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-MediumItalic.ttf
        #   style: italic
        #   weight: 500
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf
        #   weight: 600
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
        #   style: italic
        #   weight: 600
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf
        #   weight: 700
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-BoldItalic.ttf
        #   style: italic
        #   weight: 700
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-ExtraBold.ttf
        #   weight: 800
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Black.ttf
        #   weight: 900
        # - asset: fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-BlackItalic.ttf
        #   style: italic
        #   weight: 900
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**addperson.dart (This is where the function is called)
**

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:find_missing_people/utils/addMissing.dart';
import 'package:find_missing_people/utils/colors.dart';
//import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:find_missing_people/utils/pickImage.dart';
import 'package:find_missing_people/widgets/text_input_field.dart';
import 'package:firebase_dart/firebase_dart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class addPerson extends StatefulWidget {
  addPerson({super.key});

  @override
  State<addPerson> createState() => _addPersonState();
}

class _addPersonState extends State<addPerson> {
  final TextEditingController _namecontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _fathercontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _heightcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _agecontroller = TextEditingController();
  // final TextEditingController _locationcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _phonecontroller = TextEditingController();
  Uint8List? _image;

  void addImage() async {
    Uint8List img = await pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = img;
    });
  }

  // Future<String> uploadImage(String path, Uint8List file) async {
  //   if (file.isNotEmpty) {
  //     Reference ref = _storage.ref().child("missingPeopleImgs/$path");
  //     UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(file);
  //     TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
  //     String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  //     return downloadUrl;
  //   } else {
  //     return "whaaaa";
  //   }
  // }

  void addUser() async {
    String resp = "Some error ocuured";

    try {
      if (_namecontroller.text != "" ||
          _fathercontroller.text != "" ||
          _heightcontroller.text != "" ||
          _agecontroller.text != "" ||
          _phonecontroller.text != "") {
        String imgUrl =
            await StoreData().uploadImage(_namecontroller.text, _image!);
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("missing").add({
          "name": _namecontroller.text,
          "father_name": _fathercontroller.text,
          "height": _heightcontroller.text,
          "age": _agecontroller.text,
          "phone": _phonecontroller.text,
          "image": imgUrl
        });
        resp = 'Success';
      } else {
        resp = "Enter all fields";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      resp = err.toString();
    }

    if (resp == 'Success') {
      _namecontroller.clear();
      _fathercontroller.clear();
      _heightcontroller.clear();
      _agecontroller.clear();
      _phonecontroller.clear();
    }
    // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Center(
              child: Text(
                resp,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: "montserrat",
                    fontSize: 30),
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: theYellowColor,
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Add Person')),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            _image != null
                ? GestureDetector(
                    onTap: addImage,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 90,
                      backgroundImage: MemoryImage(_image!),
                    ),
                  )
                : IconButton(
                    onPressed: addImage,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_outlined),
                    iconSize: 150,
                  ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFieldInput(
                textEditingController: _namecontroller,
                hintText: "Name",
                textInputType: TextInputType.name),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFieldInput(
                textEditingController: _fathercontroller,
                hintText: "Father's Name",
                textInputType: TextInputType.name),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFieldInput(
                textEditingController: _heightcontroller,
                hintText: "Height",
                textInputType: TextInputType.name),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFieldInput(
                textEditingController: _agecontroller,
                hintText: "Age",
                textInputType: TextInputType.name),
            // const SizedBox(
            //   height: 20,
            // ),
            // TextFieldInput(
            //     textEditingController: _locationcontroller,
            //     hintText: "Location",
            //     textInputType: TextInputType.name),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFieldInput(
                textEditingController: _phonecontroller,
                hintText: "Phone number",
                textInputType: TextInputType.name),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            Center(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: addUser,
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 60,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                    color: theYellowColor,
                  ),
                  child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                    "Submit",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'montserrat',
                      fontSize: 30,
                    ),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**main.dart
**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'utils/authCheck.dart';
import 'utils/colors.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'LAAPATA',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
      ),
      home: const AuthCheck(),
    );
  }
}
```

Looks like this is the part that produces the error.
if this part is removed then it works without any problem

```
final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

class StoreData {
  Future<String> uploadImage(String childName, Uint8List file) async {
    Reference ref = _storage.ref().child(childName);
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(file);
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }
```

The error only shows up when im trying to upload an image to firebase storage. Howvever, it works if im just uploading data to firestore

I've also tried updating all the packages but didn't make any difference

Please tell me if anything else is needed